# About opening new popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, window

I have a ExtJS and jquery generated table with data fetched from database and I use this function to open new window

```
    function popUpPlayer(url) 
   {

         newWindow = window.open(url, "Flash Player", "height=255, width=735, status = no, toolbar = no, menubar = no, resizable = no", "_blank");
         if (window.focus) 
        {
            newWindow.focus()
        }
        return false;
   }
```

which works fine. But the problem is that when I click on each row of the table I want brand new window to open and load new flash player that I have.

Instead it opens just one new window and when I click on other rows of the table it just reloads the content in the same window.

Any idea how to solve this, maybe with jquery or whatever?

The rows arent "a" tags, they are "tr" tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but worth a try:

```
newWindow = window.open(url, "_blank", "height=255, width=735, status=no, toolbar=no, menubar=no, resizable=no");
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, using unique window name every time did the trick

```
function popUpPlayer(url) 
   {
         var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random()*200)+1);
         newWindow = window.open(url, rnd, "height=255, width=735, status = no, toolbar = no, menubar = no, resizable = no", "_blank");
         if (window.focus) 
        {
            newWindow.focus()
        }
        return false;
   }
```